# onCreate in an Activity ignores all the call stack sequence

Tags: java, android

**MainActivity** has an attribute `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in AndroidManifest.xml

Here's the `onCreate` method from **MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        

    Log.i(TAG,  "onCreate() from MainActivity");

    session = new TempSession(this);

    // check if logged in. If not, take the user back to login activity.
    session.checkLogin(); // <---- HERE

    Toast.makeText(this, "logged in as " + session.getUsername(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // Prevents screen from turning off when in this Activity.
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    ....
```

and the **TempSession**, it checks if user is logged in, and if not, it will take the user to the **LoginActivity**.

This is the `checkLogin()` method

```
public void checkLogin(){
    // Check login status
    if(!this.isLoggedIn() || getUsername() == null) {
        // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);

        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

        // Staring Login Activity
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

From my understanding, where I marked *<---- HERE* from MainActivity, when it calls checkLogin(), shouldn't it finish all task before it proceeds?

Currently, my app would open up LoginActivity, but still proceeds to the next instructions (e.g. makes a Toast saying "logged in as null", and keeps going on in **background**) and calls onPause() -> onStop() .

Is there any way to stop the **MainActivity** from keep going at that point?

This situation causes pressing back from **LoginActivity** bypasses to **MainActivity**.

Let me know if you need more information.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is anything in your session class reaching out to the network at that time?  I'm guessing that maybe you are on a background thread doing some work and the activity in continuing on.   I won't know for sure until I see the more code.

Comment: Not for now. That's why I named the class `TempSession`. There's no background thread/tasks created at the point of checkLogin(). AFTER checking login, the MainActivity creates multiple threads and a service to do some normal behaviors. For now, I overried the `onResume()` method and added checkLogin() function there to go to LoginActivity, but I still don't understand how it would keep going to load everything in background :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to stop the `MainActivity` from keep going at that point?

Yes.  Have `checkLogin()` return some value that indicates `MainActivity#onCreate(...)` should `return` instead of proceeding.

Calling `startActivity(...)` does not start an activity.  Think of it as asking the Android framework to start an activity.  It places this job at the end of the UI thread's work queue.  That means that before it starts the new activity, it will finish any other jobs that are already in the work queue, including the rest of the current method and possibly other lifecycle methods of the current activity.

Comment: I will go ahead and try to make that method return something. That actually make sense because it has to wait for the returning value. I'll let you know how it went (but it might take a few days) :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your toast still shows up is because merely starting a new activity does not destroy your old activity. It's merely pushed to the backstack. Of course you can change this using the `android:launchMode` attribute in your manifest. A simple strategy in your cause might be to simply return true from your checkLogin() method when the user is logged in and change your onCreate as follows:

```
if( session.checkLogin() ) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "logged in as " + session.getUsername(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // Prevents screen from turning off when in this Activity.
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great insight. I'll try your suggestion to return something.